# Word similar to guarantee

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I’m not looking for a synonym and I’m not sure what the word is for this. There are comparatives and superlatives for adjectives but I’m looking for a verb. A guarantee, assurance, or promise imply 100% likelihood of something happening (obviously this isn’t how it works in real life, I’m sticking strictly to definitions). I want a verb that is to a lesser degree than these terms.

For example instead of saying “I can guarantee your satisfaction.” I want to say “I can  your satisfaction.”

I’ve thought about this but there are only phrases such as “I promise I will try my best” or “you have my word”. A nice short verb would be preferable

Answer (score 2):

You could use the verb “endeavour”.

“I will endeavour to fulfil the contract”

Your problem is often solved by using the phrase “make best effort”.

Comment: You can, of course, "guarantee your best endeavours" without "guaranteeing a successful outcome". We can always do the former but often cannot do the latter.

Comment: Thanks. That works very nicely

Comment: @BoldBen Thanks. Your answer is well put